# Notify via email of a failed script using expect interpreter

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to have an email sent when any part of the script fails. This is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn sftp -oPort=9999 ser_s_nm@mtg-fn-serv01
expect "password:"
send "password123\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "put /folder1/folder2/report.zip\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "exit\n"
interact
```

I tried using `if` statements and exit codes to accomplish this, but the expect interpreter does not recognize `$?` as a command. How can I do this with commands that will be recognized?

Comment: Disclaimer: It has been decades since I used expect. I don't see you specifying any timeout values, so your script might hang on an error? Do you know what expect uses for return values? If so, you probably want to make this a bash script that calls expect and then checks its retval. You can use a bash here document, http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html,  that feeds your commands to expect.